Add custom Repository via external Script
I got a multi-project Gradle build, that shall add AWS CodeArtifact repositories when the credentials are configured via the global ~/.gradle/gradle.properties. If the credentials are not configured it should use mavenCentral() as fallback and output a warning.
The script is applied in every projects buildscript block but it seems, that the repositories don't have any effect, since everything gets downloaded from the central maven repo.
/build.gradle
buildscript {
    apply from: "$rootDir/buildSrc/repositories.gradle"

    repositories {
        codeArtifact("gradle-plugins")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        codeArtifact("custom-public")
    }
}

/buildSrc/repositories.gradle
ext {
    def dotCase = { String name -> "${rootProject.name}." + name.toLowerCase().replace('_', '.') }

    def getSetting = { String name ->
        def setting = System.getenv(name) ?: findProperty(dotCase(name))
        if (null == setting) {
            System.err.println("WARN: Export the '$name' env var or set '${dotCase(name)}' in your global Gradle properties")
        }
        return setting
    }

    def repositoryBaseURL = getSetting("REPOSITORY_ACCESS_URL")
    def repositoryAccessUser = getSetting("REPOSITORY_ACCESS_USER")
    def repositoryAccessPassword = getSetting("REPOSITORY_ACCESS_PASSWORD")

    codeArtifact = { String name ->
        if (repositoryBaseURL == null) {
            System.err.println("WARN: No CodeArtifact URL configured. Falling back to maven central")
            repositories.mavenCentral()
        } else {
            repositories.maven {
                url "$repositoryBaseURL/$name/"
                credentials {
                    username = repositoryAccessUser
                    password = repositoryAccessPassword
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


I tried a lot of different repository.maven, repositoryHandler.maven and other approaches, but it won't work properly.
